# Is it possible to convert existing React app to PWA and upload it to App store / Google store?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I'm looking for solution to migrate web app to mobile application platforms ASAP, and was thinking about to migrate web to pwa, and then upload to stores.

Any difficulties and pitfalls I can face with this approach?

Comment: The app store terms do not allow this. Apps that go to the app store need to be meaningfully different to their web-based counterparts, you can't just package your PWA and wrap it around say a webview and push it to the App store, Apple will either not allow it or remove it as soon as they figure. The google play store is fine with this though so the approach typically is a webview and in it you just display your website

Comment: You cannot upload a PWA to most mobile app stores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For posterity. A quick guide on converting a web application to a [progressive web application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps) (PWA).

It is relatively easy. I will summarize and get you in the right direction.

First and foremost; ensure your application is served over HTTPS for security reasons. Many core PWA technologies, such as service workers, require HTTPS.

Next include a [**manifest file**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest). [The W3 organization has a specification for the content of your `manifest.json` file which are necessary for making your application a PWA.](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#web-application-manifest)

While according to the spec, all of the manifest keys are optional, some browsers, operating systems, and app distributors have required keys for a web app to be a PWA.

If you are done playing with the `manifest.json` file, add it to your root html template. I know this is done by default in `create-react-app` but if it isn’t already, then just do this:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/*path to manifest file*/" />
</head>
```

Debugging might come in handy to ensure there are no bugs. See [Debugging Manifest Files on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Tutorials/CycleTracker/Manifest_file#debugging_manifest_files).

Next, add a [**service worker**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API). The service worker will be responsible for making the application work offline while making sure the application is always up to date. In here we:

- Specify a version for each deployment so that caches are rightly versioned.
- Specify static resources that the app needs to function.
- Install the app i.e., cache the static resources.
- Remove old caches upon new deployment.
- Intercept server requests to respond with caches etc.

Once you are done playing with your service worker, register the worker.

```js
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) navigator.serviceWorker.register(/*path to worker file*/);
```

If you also want to learn to debug service workers, see [Debugging Service Workers on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Tutorials/CycleTracker/Service_workers#debugging_service_workers).

For a good tutorial, see [CycleTracker tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Tutorials/CycleTracker).

**TL;DR**

> was thinking about to migrate web to pwa, and then upload to stores.

Some mobile application stores allow PWAs while others don’t. But is this really a necessary step? I would recommend [implementing the "Add to Home Screen" prompt <sup>[web.dev]</sup>](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/installation-prompt) to encourage users to install your PWA from your web app directly instead.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, pretty much summarises everything I needed and was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

The answer is No at least for the App store which is not PWA friendly.
You might be able to achieve this for the Play Store [here](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/pwa-in-play?hl=en)

My advice would be to code your app in [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/).
You won't need to change the logic and the way you connect your app to your back end.

If you already use the `StyleSheet` component to manage your style, the main thing you need to change in your code is the `JSX` part using the Core Component provided by React Native like the following (basic exemple)

```
// React JS

return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
)
```

to

```
// React Native

return (
    <ScrollView> // if you need the screen to be scrollable
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>...</Text>
        </View>
     <ScrollView>
)
```

Make sure to adapt the style as needed. Have a look at the shadows for exemple as it's specific to both Android and iOS.

You also have to pay attention to the React Native specific behavior, for exemple for the input, `TextInput` in RN.

```
// React JS

return (
    <div>
        ...
        <input
            value={value} 
            onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
    </div>
)
```

to

```
  // React Native

return (
    <View>
        ...
        <TextInput
            onChangeText={(text) => setValue(text)} // here 'text' is passed as a single string argument to the callback handler
            value={value}
        />
    </View>
)
```

Another tips are to check the `FlatList` Component to manage your lists instead of `map()`, and get started with `Expo` if it's your first time coding with RN as it's easier to get started with.

I acknowledge it's a bit of work because unlike React that uses React Dom to display your app on the web, React Native connects your Components to both native platforms Android and iOS, but still better than rewrite the entire app.

Comment: The OP did not ask for a native application but rather a progressive web application.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon and how to upload it to the stores...